# how to convert a microframework-w3tec function to a normal typescript function?

Tags: typescript, express

I have a function written in "microframework-w3tec" format. And now I want to exclude microframework-w3tec from the function and want to make a normal typescript function.

I am facing 1 hurdle in conversion. Below are the details :-

microframework-w3tec function

```js
import { MicroframeworkLoader, MicroframeworkSettings } from 'microframework-w3tec';
import { KafkaConsumerGroup, KafkaConsumerGroupInterface } from '../lib/kafka';
import * as Cron from 'node-cron';
import { env } from '../env';
import { SubscriberStatus, getSubscriberByStatus } from '../lib/utils';
import { Logger } from '../lib/logger';
import { mask } from '../lib/env/helpers';

const subscriberJobs: {[key: string]: KafkaConsumerGroupInterface } = {};
const log = new Logger(__filename);

export const subscriberSyncCronLoader: MicroframeworkLoader = async (settings: MicroframeworkSettings | undefined) => {
    const syncSubscriberJobs = async () => {
        try {
            const subscribers = await getSubscriberByStatus(SubscriberStatus.Active);
            const currentSubscribersSet = new Set();

            Object.keys(subscriberJobs).forEach(id => {
                if (!subscriberJobs[id].isHealthy()) {
                    subscriberJobs[id].disconnect();
                    delete subscriberJobs[id];
                    log.info(`Subscriber: ${mask(id)} is not healthy and removed`);
                }
            });

            subscribers.forEach((subscriber) => {
                const { subscriberId, callbackUrl, callbackMethod, types, updatedAt, financialId, channelId } = subscriber;
                const cgConfig = {
                    id: `${subscriberId}$${updatedAt}`,
                    groupId: `${env.kafka.consumerGroupPrefix}${subscriberId}`,
                    topics: types,
                    subscriberId,
                    financialId,
                    channelId,
                    callbackUrl,
                    callbackMethod,
                };

                currentSubscribersSet.add(cgConfig.id);
                if (!subscriberJobs[cgConfig.id]) {
                    subscriberJobs[cgConfig.id] = new KafkaConsumerGroup(cgConfig);
                    log.info(`Subscriber: ${mask(subscriberId)}$${updatedAt} added`);
                }
            });

            Object.keys(subscriberJobs).forEach(id => {
                if (!currentSubscribersSet.has(id)) {
                    subscriberJobs[id].disconnect();
                    delete subscriberJobs[id];
                    log.info(`Subscriber: ${mask(id)} removed`);
                }
            });
        } catch (error) {
            log.error('Failure while synchronizing subscribers', error);
        }
    };
    const closeAllSubscribers = () => {
        Object.keys(subscriberJobs).forEach((key) => {
            subscriberJobs[key].disconnect();
        });
    };
    const cronJob = Cron.schedule(env.cronConfig.syncCronDuration, syncSubscriberJobs);

    syncSubscriberJobs();

    if (settings) {
        settings.onShutdown(() => {
            cronJob.destroy();
            closeAllSubscribers();
        });
    }
};
```

Conversion into normal function

```js
import { KafkaConsumerGroup, KafkaConsumerGroupInterface } from '@enbdleap/node-kafka'
import * as Cron from 'node-cron';
import { env } from '../env';
import { SubscriberStatus, getSubscriberByStatus } from '../utils';
import { Logger } from '@enbdleap/node-logger';
import { mask } from '../env/helpers';

const subscriberJobs: {[key: string]: KafkaConsumerGroupInterface } = {};
const log = new Logger(__filename);

export const subscriberSyncCronLoader = () => {
    const syncSubscriberJobs = async() => {
        try {
            const subscribers = await getSubscriberByStatus(SubscriberStatus.Active);
            const currentSubscribersSet = new Set();
            
            Object.keys(subscriberJobs).forEach(id => {
                if(!subscriberJobs[id].isHealthy()){
                    subscriberJobs[id].disconnect();
                    delete subscriberJobs[id];
                    log.info(`Subscriber: ${mask(id)} not healthy and removed`);
                }
            });
            subscribers.forEach((subscriber) => {
                const { subscriberId, callbackUrl, callbackMethod, types, updatedAt, financialId, channelId } = subscriber;
                const cgConfig = {
                    id: `${subscriberId}$${updatedAt}`,
                    groupId: `${env.kafka.consumerGroupPrefix}${subscriberId}`,
                    topics: types,
                    subscriberId,
                    financialId,
                    channelId,
                    callbackUrl,
                    callbackMethod,
                };
                currentSubscribersSet.add(cgConfig.id);
                if (!subscriberJobs[cgConfig.id]) {
                    subscriberJobs[cgConfig.id] = new KafkaConsumerGroup(cgConfig);
                    log.info(`Subscriber: ${mask(subscriberId)}$${updatedAt} added`);
                }
            });
            
            Object.keys(subscriberJobs).forEach(id => {
                if (!currentSubscribersSet.has(id)) {
                    subscriberJobs[id].disconnect();
                    delete subscriberJobs[id];
                    log.info(`Subscriber: ${mask(id)} removed`);
                }
            });
        }catch (error: any) {
            log.error(`Failure while synchronizing subscribers`, { error });
        }
    };
    const closeAllSubscribers = () => {
        Object.keys(subscriberJobs).forEach((key) => {
            subscriberJobs[key].disconnect();
        });
    };
    const cronJob = Cron.schedule(env.cronConfig.syncCronDuration, syncSubscriberJobs);

    syncSubscriberJobs();
};
```

I am not understanding how to replace the below code blocks:-

```js
if (settings) {
    settings.onShutdown(() => {
        cronJob.destroy();
        closeAllSubscribers();
    });
}
```

Any leads will be very helpful.